How do I find the shortest way to make a pattern using turtle in Python?
Here is a pattern that I made:
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()

for i in range(4):
    t.forward(150)
    t.right(90)

t.forward(50)
t.right(90)
t.forward(100)
t.backward(50)
t.left(90)
t.forward(100)
t.backward(50)
t.right(90)
t.forward(100)
t.backward(50)
t.right(90)
t.forward(100)

This question might be silly, but how do I find out the shortest way to make a pattern in turtle? Also, how do I shorten this code?

There is no general algorithm for simplifying arbitrary drawings, but most basic turtle patterns such as this involve a simple pattern rotated about the center. The simplest solution almost always involves 3 steps:

Draw the fundamental shape once
Position the turtle such that it's ready to draw the same shape in the next step of the rotation
Add a loop to draw the shape and reposition N times

In this case:

Draw a rectangle with one side twice as long as the other
After completing the rectangle, move the turtle away from the rectangle a half length and point it facing along the short side (hard to explain, and this is the tricky part of this pattern)
Loop the above process 4 times.

I actually figured out the tricky step 2 mostly by trial and error. I observed the direction the turtle was pointing in and reasoned about which steps were necessary to point it in the proper direction in order to draw the next shape, then played around until it worked.
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


t = Turtle()
size = 100

for _ in range(4):
    for _ in range(2):
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(size // 2)
        t.left(90)

    t.right(90)
    t.forward(size // 2)
    t.left(180)

Screen().exitonclick()



Make an object with instructions.
Make a function with loop that will go through instructions and run one by one.
Run the function with instructions as a parameter.

This way you can reuse the function for different instructions as well.

This is somewhat vague. Are you trying to suggest OP use a function?

I don't think there exists an efficient algorithm for finding the shortest code to make a pattern. If your pattern is small, you can do it manually. If it's too large for the manual approach, make an abstract representation of your pattern (graph) and use code to try all possible ways to make it.
With this simple pattern, manual approach looks usable.
Consider how you can use this part to draw the whole pattern:
t.forward(50)
t.right(90)
t.forward(100)
t.right(90)
t.forward(50)
t.right(90)
t.forward(100)
t.right(90)
t.forward(150)

If you don't mind your code getting more complex, you can define
a function like this:
def doit(t: turtle.Turtle, what: int):
    t.forward(what)
    r.right(90)

Consider how you can use this function to redefine the above snippet of code.

There are usually alternate ways to approach a drawing that might turn out simpler, or faster, or both:
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20
SIZE = 100

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle('square')
turtle.fillcolor(screen.bgcolor())
turtle.shapesize(SIZE / 2 / CURSOR_SIZE, SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.penup()
turtle.stamp()

for _ in range(3):
    turtle.circle(3 * SIZE / 4, extent=90)
    turtle.backward(SIZE/2)
    turtle.stamp()

screen.exitonclick()

And sometimes, more fun to watch!
